# How I can add a Splash Screen in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

In VB.NET there is an option to add a Splash Screen when you click Add New Window but when I do that with C#, I can't find any thing.

so

How I can add a Splash Screen in C#?

Comment: Take a look at [Windows Forms Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32421479/3110834).

Answer (score 3):

(I'm on my Mac now so I may be a bit rusty...)

You need to open up your project preferences.

Project ->  Preferences

In the first tab, select there is a dropdown menu called "Startup Object". The default is Form1.csYou should be able to change that to a splash screen window.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2010, this is really easy. Simply add an image to your Solution, then right-click on the image, and set it's Build Action to "SplashScreen".

No coding required!

[image: Setting a splash screen]

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.  Then write the following code in Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args) 
   {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      new MyApp().Run(args);
   }

   public class MyApp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
   {
      protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
      {
         this.SplashScreen = new MySplashScreen();
      }

      protected override void OnCreateMainForm() 
      {
         // Do stuff that requires time
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

         // Create the main form and the splash screen
         // will automatically close at the end of the method
         this.MainForm = new MyMainForm();
      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: @Alaxandre - Code?! - There is a convenient way to do this without code. However, i do like the idea of being able to do things pragmatically, so +1.