# Focus winform after application.run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, focus

I have 2 winforms in an application in visual studio. The first one is kind of a loading screen, making sure there are no connection problems, then a second winforms opens, which would be a login form. I use this method to close the first form and open the second one:

```cs
this.Close();
th = new Thread(opennewform); // [opennewform thread: Application.Run(new Login());]
th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
th.Start();
```

and it works fine, but when the second form opens it loses focus. I've tried adding `this.Activate`,  `this.BringtoFront`, `this.Show`  to the second form, but it doesn't work. And what I need is after the first form closes and the second one opens, this second form is the "active" form, so it always pops up. I also needed to use the close/thread method so that the first form really closes and not just `this.hide();` but actually stays in the background. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418695/windows-forms-splash-screen-show-a-form-while-loading-main-form) question for how to correctly run a splash screen.

Comment: See [Splash Screen waiting until thread finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/393870/719186)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new thread. Instead, change the start code to something like this

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show();
    Application.Run();
}
```

I.e., remove the first form from `Application.Run()`, so that the application does not exit when this form closes.

Then open the second form with

```cs
Close();
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

Now, the application will not exit automatically when you close any form. Therefore, you must exit it explicitly with `Application.Exit();`, e.g. in the `FormClosed` event of the second form.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
this.Hide();
f2.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```